# How to stop Tkinter OptionMenu from changing value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the OptionMenu to have a title/text that never changes.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def choose(*args):
    print("Choose something")
    variable.set("Choose something")

options = ["Something1", "Something2", "Something3"]
variable = StringVar()
variable.set("Choose something")
variable.trace("w", choose)
om = OptionMenu(root, variable, *options)
om.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the text changes to the selected value and changes back to the default value "Choose something" only when I hover the OptionMenu again.

Comment: Modifying a Var within a write trace on the same Var is problematic - other write traces on the Var (such as the one that updates the OptionMenu) are suppressed, as this would otherwise result in an infinite recursion.  You need to delay the modification until after the original write has completed - `root.after(1, variable.set, "Choose something")` should work, although I think you'll need to add a check to make sure that the value wasn't "Choose something" already.

Comment: What is the point of doing this?

Comment: @acw1668 I use the OptionMenu to display functions that can be done. When I choose one of the items in the OptionMenu I want the function to run immediately. Instead of having a label saying "Choose something" I can just use it as one would use "text" in Label or Button.

Comment: Then try `Menubutton` instead of `OptionMenu`.

Comment: @acw1668 No idea how I didn't find Menubutton. It's perfect for this application

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `*arg` in the choose function.
2. Line 6: Replace `variables.set` with `variables.get()`.
3. Line 12 made use of an index rather than a string.
4. In line 13, I comment out.
5. In line 14, I added `command=choose`

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def choose(choice):
    choice = variable.get()
    print(choice)


options = ["Something1", "Something2", "Something3"]
variable = StringVar()
variable.set(options[2])
#variable.trace("w", choose)
om = OptionMenu(root, variable, *options, command=choose)
om.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```